# Outputting PHP Cron Job to Log File instead of E-Mail

Tags: php, bash, cron

Love the fact that I can keep track of my PHP script outputs via e-mail, but I have some running as quickly as once every 15 minutes so this obviously causes an over-influx of e-mails. I'd like to keep things organized in a log folder with my php output included.

Here's my cron job:

```
*/15 *  *  *  *  /usr/bin/php public_html/mysite/folder/script.php
```

I've tried changing to

```
*/15 *  *  *  *  /usr/bin/php public_html/mysite/folder/script.php >> /mysite/logs/folder/$(date +"\%Y-\%m-\%d_\%H:\%M").log 2>&1
```

But I'm still receiving error output via e-mail with the error

> > /usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell: /mysite/logs/folder/2017-04-08_10:27.log: No such file or directory

How do I fix this and get my PHP output into a log or txt file?

edit:

for future reference, the proper syntax to do this is:

```
*/15  *  *  *  *  public_html/mysite/folder/script.php >> mysite/logs/folder/$(date +"\%Y-\%m-\%d_\%H:\%M").log 2>&1
```

Comment: Make sure the directory `/mysite/logs/folder/` exists. The best way is to run the command in a terminal, including the redirection and all before putting it in the crontab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is ok, check the path. You are putting `/mysite`, but is it really on the root? When you refer to the script you put `public_html/mysite`.

Make sure what the absolute path to the log file is, and update your crontab.

Comment: Awesome.  A simple fix that was spinning my head in all different directions.  I just had to remove the leading `/` from  `mysite` and it worked properly.

Comment: Note that cron **usually** runs in the home directory of the user, although that may be implementation dependant. In your case I am assuming the `mysite`is in user's home directory. I usually prefer to use absolute paths, to avoid any possible confusion. One easy way to check what's crontab's working directory is to create a line in your crontab like this: `* * * * * pwd > /tmp/pwd.txt`. You will have your answer in less than a minute, in the pwd.txt file. Just remember to remove that line from your crontab!